# Watch live news on AppleTV

Tags: appletv

Is there any way to watch live news on an AppleTV? This is the only thing that's preventing me from cutting my cable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apple TV wasn't designed for that sort of thing; it's for all intents and purposes a closed system (i.e., iTunes-stored content only).

At the same time, if you have a flat screen TV, then chances are you can hook up a PC or Mac to it using it as a monitor and grab newscasts off the web (a friend does this and it works great). Also some of the higher-end flat screens offer links to content distributed by the manufacturer (Sony's Bravia line comes to mind here).

Comment: that's terrible usability though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: there is speculation that Apple will establish an App Store for the Apple TV like it has for their other iOS devices and even OS X now.  With Apps comes the possibility of streaming live content.

Comment: @Ryan: It's all talk until the media event.

Comment: it's also highly likely considering the path all other iOS devices have taken and the amazing source of revenue its created for Apple and developers.

Comment: @Ryan: I'm not disagreeing that it could happen, I'm just saying that until that happens, it really doesn't help us out here and now.